# Why isn't video playing or is my URL not working?

Tags: url, video, video-streaming, cell, avplayer

I want to play a video by the press of a button inside of cell. In my code get no errors so I think every thing is setup correctly however when I run the simulator the video does not play. Is it the URL or do I need to add more code somewhere? What's the best way to play a video that is hosted on a website, provide it's url? If so this hasn't worked for me.

Here's is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

 class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    let urlString = "www.dailymotion.com./video/x1prji_scott-hall-vs-hollywood-hulk-hogan-sport"

    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.bounds


        player.play()
    }
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


 }

 class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(123)



        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


           view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)


            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                //possible features implemented later
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true


            })



    }

    }

 }
```

Comment: I suspect `AVPlayer` expects a video file (like `.mp4` or `3gp`) but your code is giving it a web page (`.html` file). You can use `webView` to open web pages.

Answer (score 1):

As VC.One says, the URL you are using points to a web page - i.e. a HTML page that looks like this:

[image]

In other words, you are providing the entire HTML5 page, images, Videos, CSS etc - the information a browser needs to display a whole page.

The AVPlayer is expecting a URL to a video resource - i.e. a MP4 file or a streaming index file or manifest.

Typically, sites like YouTube or DailyMotion want you to include their branding when you include a video from them.

For your example if you click the share button you will see some embed code that you can include on a web page to just include this particular video.(this is for web rather than a native player):

```js
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1prji" allowfullscreen></iframe><br /><a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1prji" target="_blank">Scott Hall vs. &quot;Hollywood&quot; Hulk Hogan</a> <i>by <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/Stinger1981" target="_blank">Stinger1981</a></i>
```

There is also an SDK to allow you embed DailyMotion videos in your app- this one if for ObjectiveC and there is a newer one for Swift also:

- https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-player-sdk-ios

Comment: So in order for me to get JUST the video file from the website and not the whole website URL how could I format the code to where it plays the video?

Comment: You really want to use thew SDK if it is a native app.